# View Modeling: List field

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a `Form` class that has a `List<FormField>`.

```
public class Form
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int templateID { get; set; }
    public List<FormField> fields { get; set; }

    public Form()
    {
        fields = new List<FormField>();
    }
}
```

The `FormField`:

```
public class FormField
{
    public object value { get; set; }
    public TemplateField templateField {get;set;}
}
```

And the `TemplateField`:

```
public class TemplateField
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string fieldDescription { get; set; }
    public TemplateFieldType type { get; set; }
}
```

My controller class:

public class MedicalAppointment : Controller
    {

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        Template template = new TemplateDataMapper().GetMedicalAppointmentTemplate();
        Form form = new Form();
        form.templateID = template.ID;
        foreach(TemplateField field in template.fields)
        {
            FormField formField = new FormField();
            formField.templateField = field;
            form.fields.Add(formField);
        }
        return View(form);
    }

    public IActionResult TemplateManagement()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void SaveForm(Form form)
    {
          ......
    }
```

My view looks like this:

```
@model Form
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveForm", "MedicalAppointment", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "registerDonorForm" }))
{
    <table class="personal-data">
        @for(int i=0; i<Model.fields.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => Model.fields[i].templateField.ID, Model.fields[i].templateField.fieldDescription)</th>
                <th>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => Model.fields[i].value)</th>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    <div class="register-button">
        <input type="submit" value="Registar" />
    </div>
}
</div>
```

I want to create a dynamic form, where when I submit it, I could receive a Form with the `field[i].value`.

**My problem** is that, when I submit the form, in the controller, I don't receive any value submitted by the user. The Form is received with the FormField.Value null as well the Form.FormField.TemplateField.ID.

Any one can help me with that?

*Note: Forget the class names on html and other wrong names.*

Thank you in advance

Comment: So what problems are you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated the question so can be more clear. Please let me know if you have more doubts

Comment: The only form control you generate is for the `value` property of each `FormField`, so all other properties will be their default values, but the `value` property will be bound based on the code you have shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I checked againned. Everythings is equals to my code. still, I the Form on the HttpPost controller is receiving the Form as default values without set anything :S I'm debugging that